# Which Stack Exchange site is fitting to ask about joining metal sheets?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question is about how to temporary join two thin metal sheets. Where can I ask this question?

Comment: Lifehacks seems relevant. However, no authoritative answer can be given unless you supply us with more details, like an example question.

Comment: @iDebug It is not a life hack... 1 am going to join 2 1mm aluminium sheet at 90degree such that i can later remove it... so i can't even weld it

Comment: Please edit this post with your intended question, the way you want to post it.

Comment: @Ano no need for the full question in [tag:site-recommendation] questions, that would usually be just noise. Enough to describe in general what the question is about, then we can give proper advice. Sometimes we need more details indeed, but usually just the general description is enough. e.g. here "question about joining metal sheets" should be sufficient, and the given answer seems correct.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I usually find it useful if the OP includes their full intended question, so we can also advise if it's on- or off-topic on the intended site. Without it, we have no info on whether or not it's considered good, on-topic by the site's standards.

Comment: @Ano that's not our role to judge, in my opinion. site-rec questions are to get general idea where to post, not something set in stone. After getting the advice, the OP should check in the site meta, see other similar questions, etc, and decide if it's proper to post there or not. Again, that is only my own opinion, and I personally don't like seeing full off topic questions asked here masked as site-rec.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If it's in quote markup, and states explicitly that it's seeking a site recommendation, it's on-topic. In practice, people don't usually pay full attention to the site help pages and meta, so it's better to advise them early so they don't have a bad experience.

Comment: @Ano still, it feels too much like spoon feeding. And by letting them post the full question here, it opens the gate for others who will do the same then when seeing their question closed will claim "but we just wanted to ask where we can post it".

Answer (score 5):

[Home Improvement Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) sounds like it may fit your question, although just barely, depending on the exact phrasing and details.

There's also a [Metal Workers](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113930/metal-workers) proposal on Area 51 that would sound perfect for such a question, but it has not yet launched and is still in the definition phase.